# Equate reals by multiplication for arbitrarily large integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

How do I prove this statement?

$\forall x,y>0\in\mathbb R, \forall\delta >0\exists n_1, n_2\in\mathbb N$ such that $|n_1x-n_2y|<\delta$

I have tried to prove it observing that by the density of rationals numbers wrt real numbers I have $\forall x\in\mathbb R, \forall\varepsilon>0\exists \bar x\in\mathbb Q$ such that $|x-\bar x|<\varepsilon$. Then I can solve the equation above exactly with respect to $\bar x$ and $\bar y$ (namely $n_1\bar x - n_2\bar y = 0$) and by density I get $|n_1x - n_2y|\leq (\varepsilon_xn_1+\varepsilon_yn_2)$, which in my view is not good, since I have an arbitrarily small quantity times an arbitrarily large quantity.

The book I'm reading says that the proof is trivial: can someone help me?

Comment: why don't you just let $n_1=y$ and $n_2=x$, your difference is $0$.

Comment: $n_1$ and $n_2$ should be integers, $x$ and $y$ are real!

Comment: can you prove it if $x$ and $y$ are rational instead? with something along similar lines?

Comment: Yes, I can prove it for rationals! The problem is with reals

Comment: Then prove that you can take some rational $x'$ arbitrarily close to a real $x$, and you're done.

Comment: Excuse me, but have you read all the question? There's a fundamental problem with that approach

Comment: Yes, I have read the question. I am saying there is no fundamental problem with that approach. Yes, you're multiplying arbitrarily small numbers with arbitrarily large ones, but *you* choose the small numbers. You can make them as small as you wish.

Comment: Correct, but the large numbers are a function of the small ones... (they come after I choose the small ones)

Comment: You sure about that? You have $n_1$ and $n_2$ before hand, $\varepsilon_x$ and $\varepsilon_y$ are being selected later.

Comment: No, it's (1) I choose $\bar x$ and $\bar y$, and therefore the epsilons, (2) I solve the equation getting $n_1$ and $n_2$... they come after

Comment: Are you familiar with Dirichlet's Theorem on Diophantine Approximation?

Comment: Not really, actually... the identity came up while I was studying almost periodic functions. Which theorem?

Comment: I have told you which theorem --- I gave you its name. I think you may find it applies here, and I encourage you to read up on it.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look up that theorem?

Comment: I did, and after that everything worked fine! Thank you

Comment: If you now know how to answer your question, you can post an answer. Then, when the software permits, you can accept your answer. This helps clear up the Unanswered Questions list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I solved the problem.

The crucial result is Dirichlet's approximation theorem, which states that $\forall\alpha\in\mathbb R\forall N\in\mathbb N\ \exists p,q\in \mathbb N$ such that $|p\alpha-q|<\frac{1}{N+1}$. Then one observes (I use the notation of my question) $|n_1x-n_2y| = y\Big|n_1\frac{x}{y}-n_2\Big|<\frac{y}{N+1}$ by the previous theorem.